# Переменное число аргументов

Tags: c++

Объясните, как работает передаче переменного количества значений в прототипе функции f? Почему тут явно указан тип S, в то время когда в других примерах использования передачи переменного числа значений, тип передаваемых значений не указывается?(просто пишут многоточие).
Как работать с переданными значениями?

```
enum S {A,B,C};
void f(int n, S ...);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых в записи `void f(int n, S ...);` `S` не задает тип передаваемых значений. На самом деле эта запись эквивалентна `void f(int n, S /*unnamed*/, ...);`, т.е. S - эти тип второго аргумента без имени.

Тип значений, передаваемых через `...` вообще никак не задается. Они передаются как блок, содержащий указатели `void *`, `double` и целочисленные типы (в соответствии с правилами преобразования для целочисленных типов).

Также не стоит путать variadic функции с шаблонами функций, где как раз можно задавать тип передаваемых значений:

```
template<typename ... Values>
void f(int, Values ... values);
```

`Values` - пак с типами параметров

Comment: Почему тогда запятую можно не ставить?

Comment: @J.John Ну такой уж синтаксис. Причем variadic функции были еще в C, так что тут получается некоторая неконсистентность по отношению к variadic шаблонам функций, в которых `...` имеет другое значение.

Comment: Как правильно реализовать передачу переменного количества перечислителей из enum S?

Comment: @J.John Это уже годится для нового вопроса. Обязательно с уточнением, что означает "правильно". В принципе приведенный variadic шаблон вполне на это способен (особенно если добавить проверку типа передаваемых значений через `static_assert`).

Comment: Не совсем понятно утверждение про "блок, содержащий указатели `void *`, `double` и целочисленные типы". В С++ (да и в С) через `...` можно предавать существенно большее разнообразие типов данных. Фактически, этот "блок" может содержать что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Из стандарта: 8.3.5.4:

Там, где это синтаксически корректно и где лексема «...» не является частью абстрактного-описателя, форма «,...» считается синонимом формы «...».

Так что это просто функция, получающая аргументы `int`, `S` и что угодно. Синоним

```
void f(int n, S, ...);
```